# Are two java files in a directory considered a "package?"

Tags: java, package

I have a directory that contains the following :

1) A.java
2) B.java

Is this all that is required in order to call my directory a java 'package'? What if I compile both of them resulting in a directory with two additional .class files? Can it be considered a package then or are there other requirements/actions to take?

Comment: Two Java files are in the same package if they have the same `package` directive.  They do not actually need to be in the same directory (though it's a good idea).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files must begin with a package declaration that matches the directory in which they are located.

For example :

`package com.something;`

if the files are located under `com/something`.

```
com/
    something/
        A.java
        B.java
```

Comment: I don't think the package name necessarily needs to match the directory structure (though it is of course good practice).

Comment: @MrHug The JLS does not require it, but many implementations of Java rely on it. See [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/managingfiles.html).

Comment: As @MrHug said it is not necessary that the source files are in the same directory structure as the package declaration. The package declaration in the source file is what determines a classes package. However it has become a convention as well as a good practice. Since this is the case many tools have been developed expecting this behaviour.

Comment: In order for the class loader to find the .class file, it must be in a directory corresponding to the package name, relative to the starting point called out by the class path.  But different classes in the same package can be in different absolute paths, so long as the above requirement is met.  And the .java files do not need to follow this rule, though compiling is messy if they don't.

Comment: @markbernard Again, it's not necessary according to the JLS, but if, for example, you try to change the package name of a file in Eclipse without moving it to the corresponding directory, you'll get an error.

Comment: @Eran correct, which is why I said it has become practice that everyone follows and many tools expect this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To be in the same package, the files must both contain the line:

```
package com.example.samepackage;
```

(for example)

Answer (score 0):

Package is like directory structure but don't confuse it with window's or other OS' folder.

Just consider package as a package of files.

Just write:
package anything;

as the top most line in your program. All the files have same package name will be placed in the same "anything" package and hence can be used for further implementation like "import amything;" if you want to use those files in any other program and then use those files' structure.